# Difference between systemd's "System unit directories" and "User unit directories"

Tags: linux, systemd

I am currently reading the [systemd manual page](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.html), where under the section [directories](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.html#Directories) it discriminates between the unit directory types "System unit directories" and "User unit directories".

I am unsure as to what is meant by this.

In the [systemd.unit manual page](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#), the terms "system mode" and "user mode" are used. Are these terms related to the directory path types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ArchWiki on [systemd/User](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Systemd/User) describes the User units rather well:

> **systemd** offers the ability to manage services under the user's control
> with a per-user systemd instance, enabling them to start, stop,
> enable, and disable their own **user units**. This is convenient for
> daemons and other services that are commonly run for a single user,
> such as mpd, or to perform automated tasks like fetching mail.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out.

> systemd offers the ability to manage services under the user's control with a per-user systemd instance, enabling them to start, stop, enable, and disable their own user units. This is convenient for daemons and other services that are commonly run for a single user, such as mpd, or to perform automated tasks like fetching mail.

Source: [Archlinux wikipedia entry](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Systemd/User)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).